# How did Alan Albright's parents have sex?

Tags: ben-10

Alan's parents were a human and a heatblast (an alien literally made of fire) how did they have sex without either burning his father's dick off or killing the sperms?

Comment: I think there are larger issues with biological hybridization of humans and fire.

Comment: 1. Are you sure that pyronites have to have sex to procreate?
2. Apparently Alan's origin was retconned, so that he was born human and only later made in to a hybrid.

Comment: The fact that he had a heatblast mother And a human father implies that they reproduce sexually. Like you're not going to have a hybrid child with a species that reproduce asexuality. But I'm satisfied with you answer that he was born fully human and was given heatblast DNA later

Answer (score 1):

According to [fandom](https://ben10.fandom.com/wiki/Alan_Albright#Trivia):

> Originally, Alan's father was a Pyronite... This was retconned in
> Omniverse, as it is revealed that Alan was fully human and given
> Pyronite abilities by Kevin and an unnamed Pyronite.